# Fetching error in release version of react-native app

Tags: android, react-native, fetch

I'm trying to test release version of my app on android but getting an error err while fetching an external data:

```
{"line"115,"column":7258,"sourceURL":"index.android.bundle"}
```

In debug version all works fine.

My code:

```
let url = 'http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:99/app/all'

fetch(url, { mode: 'no-cors' })
  .then((resp) => resp)
  .catch((err) => {
    dispatch(fetchErrText(JSON.stringify(err)))
  })
```

I've made bugreport of release version with **adb bugreport** which gave me this result:

```
--------- beginning of crash 
09-09 01:05:38.286 10350 20734 21089 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules 
09-09 01:05:38.286 10350 20734 21089 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.mightio.signal, PID: 20734 
09-09 01:05:38.286 10350 20734 21089 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Too many receivers, total of 1000, registered for pid: 20734, callerPackage: com.mightio.signal 
09-09 01:05:38.286 10350 20734 21089 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1961) 
09-09 01:05:38.286 10350 20734 21089 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1921) 
09-09 01:05:38.286 10350 20734 21089 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1871) 
09-09 01:05:38.286 10350 20734 21089 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.registerReceiver(IActivityManager.java:3732) 
09-09 01:05:38.286 10350 20734 21089 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1498) 
09-09 01:05:38.286 10350 20734 21089 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1459) 
09-09 01:05:38.286 10350 20734 21089 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1447) 
09-09 01:05:38.286 10350 20734 21089 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:633) 
09-09 01:05:38.286 10350 20734 21089 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.android.billingclient.api.BillingBroadcastManager$BillingBroadcastReceiver.register(BillingBroadcastManager.java:81) 
09-09 01:05:38.286 10350 20734 21089 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.android.billingclient.api.BillingBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(BillingBroadcastManager.java:53) 
09-09 01:05:38.286 10350 20734 21089 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientImpl.startConnection(BillingClientImpl.java:298) 
09-09 01:05:38.286 10350 20734 21089 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.dooboolab.RNIap.RNIapModule.initConnection(RNIapModule.java:138) 
09-09 01:05:38.286 10350 20734 21089 E AndroidRuntime:  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
09-09 01:05:38.286 10350 20734 21089 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372) 
09-09 01:05:38.286 10350 20734 21089 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:151) 
09-09 01:05:38.286 10350 20734 21089 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
09-09 01:05:38.286 10350 20734 21089 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
09-09 01:05:38.286 10350 20734 21089 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
09-09 01:05:38.286 10350 20734 21089 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27) 
09-09 01:05:38.286 10350 20734 21089 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
09-09 01:05:38.286 10350 20734 21089 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226) 
09-09 01:05:38.286 10350 20734 21089 E AndroidRuntime:  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
09-09 01:05:38.286 10350 20734 21089 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace: 
09-09 01:05:38.286 10350 20734 21089 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.registerReceiver(ActivityManagerService.java:21653) 
09-09 01:05:38.286 10350 20734 21089 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact$registerReceiver$(IActivityManager.java:10227) 
09-09 01:05:38.286 10350 20734 21089 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:155) 
09-09 01:05:38.286 10350 20734 21089 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3400) 
09-09 01:05:38.286 10350 20734 21089 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:726)
```

Comment: My problem was in fetching data with not-secure link http